# Database Design Relationship

Tags: database-design

I have two tables:

### Food

id, name, unit, createdDate, lastUpdate

### Ingredients

id, name, quantity, unit, food_id_fk, createdDate, lastUpdate

The problem is a food can be divided into two categories and each category can have it own
set of ingredients. Also a food might not have categories. How is it done? Your help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: dont you think then ingredientId should be part of Food?

Comment: Food "Nasik Lemak" has two categories which is "Coconut Rice" and "Sambal Ikan Belis". In each category there are ingredients. Here is a sample link [link](http://www.malaysianfood.net/recipes/recipenasilemak.htm). If the food is "Spagheti then it does not have categories. Here is a sample link [link](http://norecipes.com/recipe/spaghetti-meat-sauce-recipe/)

Comment: You'll want to look into creating a third pivot table for your relationships.  I would even look into using an ORM, unless you like writing join sql statements :)

Comment: You need a mapping table between food and ingredient.

Comment: ORM?  I see no objects here.  JOINs are easy enough to write; no need for an ORM SQL generator.  I can write a SELECT in one line.  Try that with your ORM sometime.

Comment: `$food = Food::where('name', 'pizza')->get()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you try something like this:

Food (**id**, name, servingSize, servingUnit, totalServings, createdDate, lastUpdate)

Ingredient (**id**, name, unit, createdDate, lastUpdate)

Category (**id**, name, createdDate, lastUpdate)

Recipe (**food_id_fk, category_id_fk**, **ingredient_id_fk**, quantity,comments)

**PrimaryKey**

Notice that I've created a table named "Recipe" that will allow you to have multiple ingredients for each relation food-category. If an specific product "doesn't have a category" just use the Category Id = 0 (for example: General Category)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a basic understanding of database design. Don't you just need a categories table with a column for food ID and an ingredients table with a column for category ID? A food with no categories would have no entries in the categories table.

Comment: [Food: id, name, unit, createdDate, lastUpdate], [Group: id, name, food_id_fk], [Ingredients:id, name, quantity, unit, group_id_fk, item_id_fk, createdDate, lastUpdate]. Like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, so there's no surprise that you're having trouble.

Don't worry about the SQL yet; worry about the relationships.

I don't think Food should have unit as a column.  The fact that I use a cup of chopped solid or 8 oz of pureed Carrot in a recipe will influence units but not change the essence of Carrot.

I think Ingredient ought to have a 1:many relationship with Food.

I don't see the purpose for the updated date column on Food.  I picture those as read-only data that won't change.

Do you expect to have a Recipe table 1:many with Ingredients?  What about steps?  Most recipes do things in a certain sequence, where each step takes a certain amount of time.

Comment: The unit is like "1 burger", "1 chicken wing" rather than the ingredient measurement such as "tbl, ml, gram" and so forth.

Comment: could be in some cases.  might be my units in others.